# how to call on a method outside of the main method in java

Tags: java, methods, program-entry-point

I have a method outside of the main method that averages. At the end of the main I am calling on that averaging method. I am not understaning the propper way to 
1. use variables I declare with other methods in this program. for example the sum which is defined in the calculate_average method. 
or 
The sum which is defined in the main method.

Please show me

1. how to interchange variables in and out of the main method. interchangeably between methods that are not in main.
2. call on a method outside of main in main to calculate the average.

Here is my current code.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

class programTwo
{

    private static Double calculate_average( ArrayList<Double> myArr )
    {
        Double Sum = 0.0;
        for (Double number: myArr)
        {
            Sum += number;
        }

    }

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<Double> myArr = new ArrayList<Double>();
        double Sum = 0;
        int count = 0;
        System.out.println("Enter a number to be averaged, repeat up to 20 times:");
        String inputs = scan.nextLine();

    while (!inputs.matches("[qQ]") )
    {

        if (count == 20)
        {
            System.out.println("You entered more than 20 numbers, you suck!");
            break;
        }

        Scanner scan2 = new Scanner(inputs); // create a new scanner out of our single line of input
        myArr.add(scan2.nextDouble());
        count += 1;
        System.out.println("Please enter another number or press Q for your average");

        inputs = scan.nextLine();
    }
    Double average = calculate_average(myArr);
    System.out.println("Your average is: " + average);

    return Sum / myArr.size();

}}
```

Comment: make the calculate_average method static

Comment: @Neil isn't it already?

Comment: I'm unclear on your goal.

Comment: Hey look there it is - don't know why I didn't see it the first time...

Comment: I was just gonna edit my comment.  I'm lost at what your actual question is.

Comment: how to make this program work while keeping the calculate_average method outside of main.

Comment: Do you want to call it from another class? If so make it public,

Comment: You surely need to follow naming convention see [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html#367)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have this at the end of `main`:

```
return Sum / myArr.size();
```

You need to move it to `calculate_average`:

```
private static Double calculate_average( ArrayList<Double> myArr )
{
    Double Sum = 0.0;
    for (Double number: myArr)
    {
        Sum += number;
    }

    return Sum / myArr.size();
}
```

Given that `main` is `void` and an average makes no sense as an exit code even if it weren't, I'm assuming that is some kind of typographical error.

### Some code review

- Local variables should start with a lower case letter. So `sum`, not `Sum`
- You can use the primitive `double` instead of a `Double` object. Using the object will cause boxing/unboxing overhead.
- Indent your `while` loop and its contents by four more spaces so the loop beginning  aligns vertically with the code above it because it's in the same block (the method's block).
- Split those last 2 braces into separate lines
- Line up the last two braces vertically with the matching opening brace
- You've started by creating your `calculate_average` method, but continue breaking up `main`. It's too long. Too much is going on there.
- Change `if (count == 20)` to `if (count >= 20)`. Harder to mess up, then.

Answer (score 1):

i think you have **static method**,
so you can call them bye using **className.MethodName** Directly.

Just Declare your method as public and you can call them outside also.

```
 programTwo.calculate_average(myArr)
```

**No need to create object for calling static methods.**

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing I can see wrong with your code, except **you are missing a return statement in your `calculate_average` method**.

Also, if you name a method `calculate_average`, it should return the *average* not the *sum*.

Try this:

```
private static Double calculate_average( ArrayList<Double> myArr )
{
    Double sum = 0.0;
    for (Double number: myArr)
    {
        sum += number;
    }
    return sum/myArr.size(); // added return statement
}
```

Comment: but its dividing the sum of the array but the size of the array to find the average. Is that a bad way to do that?

Comment: Yes. it's bad. Either call the method `getSum()` and return the sum, or call it `getAverage()` and return the average. Having a method name not agree with its behaviour leads to confusion and bugs. You could consider having a summing method that the average method calls.